# Hold input values in local state, but pass to parent to submit form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, parent-child, react-state

I am new to React and learning by building a simple timesheet application that users can fill out and when it submits, it posts the data to a SharePoint list using a SharePoint API (see below).

[image]

**How I want it to work**
The tool has been created using a table and each row is a table row stored in a child component. When a user clicks the 'add a task' button this creates a new table row, where they can add the time they have completed for that individual task. They can add as many items as they need, then when they hit the 'submit' button, this submits each individual task to the Sharepoint list as separate items.

**My Issue**
At the moment when a user adds a task, then adds text to the input field. It is passed up to the parent state, where the data will need to be submitted, but this means that when you enter text into one of the rows, it is reflected in ALL rows. When I store the data in the local state, there is no way of passing the values up to the parent state, so that all tasks can be submitted in one click, but store unique values. I want to know if there is anyway for the values for each row to be stored in the components local state, so they are unique, but to pass the value up to the parent state, so they can all be submitted together? Or of the proper way you should deal with this in React?

**The Code**
So I have a parent component called TimesheetTool, that includes an empty array of tasks and the main table (each task the user wants to add to the timesheet tool is added as a table row). Then inside the table body I have mapped the tr to pull the table row from a child component called 'TableRow'.

**Parent Component**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import styles from './TimesheetTool.module.scss';
import { ITimesheetToolProps } from './ITimesheetToolProps';
import { escape } from '@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset';
import { ISpfxReactCrudState } from './ISpfxReactCrudState'; 
import { IListItem } from './IListItem';  
import { SPHttpClient, SPHttpClientResponse } from '@microsoft/sp-http';
import TableRow from './TableRow';


export default class TimesheetTool extends React.Component<ITimesheetToolProps, ISpfxReactCrudState> {
  constructor(props: ITimesheetToolProps, state: ISpfxReactCrudState) {  
      super(props);  

      this.state = {
        project:'', task:'', mon:0, tues:0, wed:0, thurs:0, fri:0, sat:0, sun:0,
        status: 'Ready',  
        items: [],
        tasks: []
      };
  }

  handleProjectChange = (event) => {this.setState({project: event.target.value}); console.log('Event:', event.target.value)}
  handleTaskChange = (event) => {this.setState({task: event.target.value})};
  handleMonChange = (event) => {this.setState({mon: event.target.value})};
  handleTuesChange = (event) => {this.setState({tues: event.target.value})};
  handleWedChange = (event) => {this.setState({wed: event.target.value})};
  handleThursChange = (event) => {this.setState({thurs: event.target.value})};
  handleFriChange = (event) => {this.setState({fri: event.target.value})};
  handleSatChange = (event) => {this.setState({sat: event.target.value})};
  handleSunChange = (event) => {this.setState({sun: event.target.value})};

  handleAddTask = (task) => {
    task.preventDefault();
    const tasks = [...this.state.tasks];
    this.setState({ tasks: this.state.tasks.concat(task) });
  }

  handleDelete = (index) => () => this.setState({tasks: this.state.tasks.filter((_, i) => i !== index)})


    public render(): React.ReactElement<ITimesheetToolProps > {  
      const items: JSX.Element[] = this.state.items.map((item: IListItem, i: number): JSX.Element => {  
        return (  
          <li>{item.Title} ({item.Id}) </li>  
        );  
      });  

      return (
        <div>
          <form>
            <button onClick={this.handleAddTask} >Add a Task</button>
            <table className={styles.table}>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Project</th>
                  <th>Task</th>
                  <th>Monday</th>
                  <th>Tuesday</th>
                  <th>Wednesday</th>
                  <th>Thursday</th>
                  <th>Friday</th>
                  <th>Saturday</th>
                  <th>Sunday</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                {this.state.tasks.map((task, index) => 
                  <tr key={index}>
                    <TableRow
                      handleProjectChange={this.handleProjectChange}
                      handleTaskChange = {this.handleTaskChange}
                      handleMonChange = {this.handleMonChange}
                      handleTuesChange = {this.handleTuesChange}
                      handleWedChange = {this.handleWedChange}
                      handleThursChange = {this.handleThursChange}
                      handleFriChange = {this.handleFriChange}
                      handleSatChange = {this.handleSatChange}
                      handleSunChange = {this.handleSunChange}
                      project={this.state.project}
                      task={this.state.task}
                      mon={this.state.mon}
                      tues={this.state.tues}
                      wed={this.state.wed}
                      thurs={this.state.thurs}
                      fri={this.state.fri}
                      sat={this.state.sat}
                      sun={this.state.sun}
                    />
                    <td><a href="#" onClick={this.handleDelete(index)}>Delete</a></td> 
                  </tr>
                )}
              </tbody>
            </table>
            <div>
            <a href="#" onClick={() => this.createItem()}><span>Submit</span> </a>
            </div> 
          </form>

          <div>  
            {this.state.status}  
            <ul>  
              {items}
            </ul>  
          </div>  
        </div>  
      );  
    }

    private createItem(): void {  
      this.setState({  
        status: 'Creating item...',  
        items: []  
      });  

      const body: string = JSON.stringify({  
        'Title': `Submitted: ${new Date()}`,
        'Project': `${this.state.project}`,
        'Task': `${this.state.task}`,
        'Monday': `${this.state.mon}`,
        'Tuesday': `${this.state.tues}`,
        'Wednesday': `${this.state.wed}`,
        'Thursday': `${this.state.thurs}`,
        'Friday': `${this.state.fri}`,
        'Saturday': `${this.state.sat}`,
        'Sunday': `${this.state.sun}`
      });  

      this.props.spHttpClient.post(`${this.props.siteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('${this.props.listName}')/items`,  
      SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,  
      {  
        headers: {  
          'Accept': 'application/json;odata=nometadata',  
          'Content-type': 'application/json;odata=nometadata',  
          'odata-version': ''  
        },  
        body: body  
      })  
      .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse): Promise<IListItem> => {  
        return response.json();  
      })  
      .then((item: IListItem): void => {  
        this.setState({  
          status: `Timesheet Successfully Submitted`,  
          items: []  
        });  
      }, (error: any): void => {  
        this.setState({  
          status: 'Error while submitting timesheet' + error,  
          items: []  
        });  
      });  
    }    
}
```

**Child Component**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Component, createRef } from 'react';
import { ITimesheetToolProps } from './ITimesheetToolProps';
import { ISpfxReactCrudState } from './ISpfxReactCrudState'; 

export default class TableRow extends React.Component<ITimesheetToolProps, ISpfxReactCrudState> {      

    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <td><input type="text" name="project" value={this.props.project} onChange={(event) => this.props.handleProjectChange(event)} /></td>
                <td><input type="textarea" name="task" value={this.props.task} onChange={(event) => this.props.handleTaskChange(event)} /></td>
                <td><input type="number" name="mon" value={this.props.mon} onChange={(event) => this.props.handleMonChange(event)} /></td>
                <td><input type="number" name="tues" value={this.props.tues} onChange={(event) => this.props.handleTuesChange(event)} /></td>
                <td><input type="number" name="wed" value={this.props.wed} onChange={(event) => this.props.handleWedChange(event)} /></td>
                <td><input type="number" name="thurs" value={this.props.thurs} onChange={(event) => this.props.handleThursChange(event)} /></td>
                <td><input type="number" name="fri" value={this.props.fri} onChange={(event) => this.props.handleFriChange(event)}/></td>
                <td><input type="number" name="sat" value={this.props.sat} onChange={(event) => this.props.handleSatChange(event)} /></td>
                <td><input type="number" name="sun" value={this.props.sun} onChange={(event) => this.props.handleSunChange(event)} /></td>
            </React.Fragment>        
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That because your each row binds with one single js object.
your code need to be changed as below

This is for first row

```
value={this.props[0].sun}
```

This is for second row

```
  value={this.props[1].sun}
```

===================>

```
 <tbody>
                {this.state.tasks.map((task, index) => 
                  <tr key={index}>
                    <TableRow
                      project={this.state.project}
                      task={this.state.task}
                      mon={this.state.mon}
                      tues={this.state.tues}
                      wed={this.state.wed}
                      thurs={this.state.thurs}
                      fri={this.state.fri}
                      sat={this.state.sat}
                      sun={this.state.sun}
                    />
                    <td><a href="#" onClick={this.handleDelete(index)}>Delete</a></td> 
                  </tr>
                )}
              </tbody>
```

in this bit, you are passing data down to the tablerow component, but every row points to one js object which is this.state
You have to change to collection. it could be `task.project` something like. Anyhow, each row must point to one unique js object in your collection of data.

Comment: Where are you suggesting these rows go? Could you show me in my code?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do a bit separation of concern where the Parent will manage your list of tasks while the Child component will handle each. Something like below should work for you.

```js
// Parent

export default class TimesheetTool extends React.Component<ITimesheetToolProps, ISpfxReactCrudState> {
  ...
  onUpdateTask = (index, item) => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      task: prevState.task.map((task, i) => {
        return index === i ? item : task
      })
    })
  }
  ...
  render () {
    ...
    {this.state.tasks.map((task, index) => 
      <tr key={index}>
        <TableRow index={index} onUpdateTask={this.onUpdateTask} /> // pass down a callback
      </tr>
    )}
    ...
  }
})

// Child

export default class TableRow extends React.Component<ITimesheetToolProps, ISpfxReactCrudState> {

  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      project:'',
      task:'',
      mon:0,
      tues:0,
      ...
    };
  }

  onChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target
    this.setState({
      [name]: value,
    }, () => {
      this.props.onUpdateTask(this.props.index, this.state) // call the parent that the task of this index has changed
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <td><input type="text" name="project" value={this.state.project} onChange={this.onChange} /></td>
        <td><input type="textarea" name="task" value={this.state.task} onChange={this.onChange} /></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="mon" value={this.state.mon} onChange={this.onChange} /></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="tues" value={this.state.tues} onChange={this.onChange} /></td>
        ...
      </React.Fragment>        
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: I get a typescript error "prevstate.task.map is not a function" when I try this code. Could you please explain to me what the following function is doing? As this is a bit confusing to me. onUpdateTask = (index, item) => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      task: prevState.task.map((task, i) => {
        return index === i ? item : task
      })
    }))
  }